# Error: random is not a function solidity/web3js

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

I am trying pull a random number generated from a function on my smart contract that uses the' block difficulty' and the 'block time stamp'.

The solidity code looks like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

 contract ApprovalContract {

  function random() external view returns (uint8){
  return uint8(uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.timestamp, 
  block.difficulty)))%251);
  } 
 ...
 }
```

The application code written in JS looks like this:

```
ApprovalContract.methods.random().call(
        function(error, result) {
            if (error) {
              console.log('error: ' + error);
            }
            else {
              console.log('result: ' + JSON.stringify(result));
            }
          });
```

All I need to do is log the randomly generated number to the console. Unfortunately, I keep seeing

> Uncaught TypeError: ApprovalContract.methods.random is not a function

Comment: Change it to `ApprovalContract.methods.random.call(...)` (No parentheses on `random`)

Comment: @AdamKipnis 

    index.html:204 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (index.html:204)
    at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)
    at HTMLFormElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)

also I can't see my 'random' function listed as a method in the contract object

Answer (score 0):

You have not posted your whole JS code so it is unclear how you are getting ApprovalContract. Ideally it should be as below. You will need web3js version greater than 1.0 for this code to work. The version that I have used is 1.0.0-beta.34.

```
var approvalcontract_artifact = require('../build/contracts/ApprovalContract.json'); /*Please insert path of your ApprovalContract.json in here */
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3('https://ropsten.infura.io/7dsXakGVRMs1EwuYwkQv'); /*Your Client Endpoint */

var ApprovalContract = new web3.eth.Contract(approvalcontract_artifact.abi, '0x3f6eeae6bb291ed249a4cbff22c49f0ce96b723a'); /* Please write your contract address in place of this address */

var random = ApprovalContract.methods.random().call()
    .then(function(result){
       console.log('result: ' + JSON.stringify(result));
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log('error: ' + error);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

be careful when your are using pseudo randomness on blockchain, it's fine for testing, but for applications with a lot of money it's dangerous because it's exploitable,

for that purpose you need to use some form of [verified randomness](https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-vrf/)

***here is a tutorial >>>*** [randomness tutorial](https://docs.chain.link/docs/get-a-random-number/) ***<<<***